# SQL Query return zero if is NOT in list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the followin

```
SELECT
       au.country as country_code,
       COALESCE(SUM(uwm.amount), 0) as amountInbound
        FROM user_wallet_movement uwm
        LEFT JOIN user_wallet uw ON uwm.wallet_id = uw.id
        LEFT JOIN app_user au ON uw.user_id = au.id
        WHERE
              status = 'execute'
              and direction = 'inbound'
              and mov_date > '2020-07-01'
              and au.country IN ('AD', 'AC', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AI', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AW', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BM', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BV', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CC', 'CD', 'CF', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CR', 'CU', 'CV', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'EH', 'ER', 'ES', 'ET', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FK', 'FM', 'FO', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GF', 'GH', 'GI', 'GL', 'GM', 'GN', 'GP', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GT', 'GU', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HM', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IO', 'IQ', 'IR', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KP', 'KR', 'KW', 'KY', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MM', 'MN', 'MP', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MS', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NC', 'NE', 'NF', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NU', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PF', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PM', 'PN', 'PR', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RE', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SD', 'SE', 'SG', 'SH', 'SI', 'SJ', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SO', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SY', 'SZ', 'TC', 'TD', 'TF', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TK', 'TL', 'TM', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'UM', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VA', 'VC', 'VE', 'VG', 'VI', 'VN', 'VU', 'WF', 'WS', 'xA', 'xE', 'xF', 'XK', 'xN', 'xO', 'xS', 'YE', 'YT', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW')
      GROUP BY country_code
      ORDER BY country_code
```

Which should return me the amount of money spent in each country in the list.
My output is

```
AE  0.35365110000000016
AR  1.0367374499999995
AT  0.11195171000000001
AU  1.7345992
BE  1.9242438800000006
BG  5.043282479999997
CA  0.5906319000000001
CH  0.5082077999999999
CO  0.14248785
CR  0.036722840000000014
CU  0.11325390999999999
CY  0.18752883999999997
CZ  0.11454307999999999
DE  8.057752660000036
DO  0.8858295500000001
EE  0.7410690900000001
ES  31.125371000000023
FR  0.4851664099999999
GB  1.44115391
HR  0.023154
HU  1.0131190899999998
IE  0.3229343799999997
IN  0.026833529999999984
IT  2199.1061043693944
KE  0.21115987
KR  0.161765
LU  0.20279967
MC  0.2127708600000001
MT  0.028277630000000005
MX  0.45381685
NL  0.1408655
PE  0.00108554
QA  1.8347713
RO  7.0233499800000105
RS  0.25260947000000006
RU  0.16577983
SE  3.4979126399999947
SH  1.1328741000000002
SI  0.00178069
SK  0.04637177
SZ  0.3603625199999996
US  2.41114205
VE  0.53491791
```

So, as you can see, there are countries in the list which not appear in the output because the amount is null.
How can I include them in the list with the value 0?
Thank you

EDIT:
Not all countries in the list are in the table; I also would like to be in the output countries that are not in the table but are in the list

Comment: The answer may depend on which RDBMS (MySQL? SQL Server?) you're using, so you may want to tag the question with that.

Comment: Your query is not clear as your are not consistently aliasing your column names. Possibly you need to use `outer` joins instead of `inner` joins.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is if you don't have data in wallet tables for given table join will return nothing. instead you can use left join :

```
SELECT
    au.country as country_code,
    COALESCE(SUM(uwm.amount), 0) as amountInbound
FROM
    app_user au
    left join user_wallet uw ON uw.user_id = au.id
    left JOIN user_wallet_movement uwm ON uwm.wallet_id = uw.id
WHERE
    status = 'execute'
    and direction = 'inbound'
    and mov_date > '2020-07-01'
au.country IN ('AD', 'AC', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AI', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AW', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BM', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BV', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CC', 'CD', 'CF', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CR', 'CU', 'CV', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'EH', 'ER', 'ES', 'ET', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FK', 'FM', 'FO', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GF', 'GH', 'GI', 'GL', 'GM', 'GN', 'GP', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GT', 'GU', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HM', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IO', 'IQ', 'IR', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KP', 'KR', 'KW', 'KY', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MM', 'MN', 'MP', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MS', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NC', 'NE', 'NF', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NU', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PF', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PM', 'PN', 'PR', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RE', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SD', 'SE', 'SG', 'SH', 'SI', 'SJ', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SO', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SY', 'SZ', 'TC', 'TD', 'TF', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TK', 'TL', 'TM', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'UM', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VA', 'VC', 'VE', 'VG', 'VI', 'VN', 'VU', 'WF', 'WS', 'xA', 'xE', 'xF', 'XK', 'xN', 'xO', 'xS', 'YE', 'YT', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW')
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY country_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `inner joins` are limiting the rows in your output, try using `outer` joins:

```
SELECT
       au.country as country_code,
       COALESCE(SUM(uwm.amount), 0) as amountInbound
        FROM user_wallet_movement uwm
        LEFT OUTER JOIN user_wallet uw ON uwm.wallet_id = uw.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN app_user au ON uw.user_id = au.id
        WHERE
              status = 'execute'
              and direction = 'inbound'
              and mov_date > '2020-07-01'
              and au.country IN (...)
      GROUP BY country_code
      ORDER BY country_code
```

Answer (score 0):

If your *data* has all the countries, then a simple fix is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT au.country as country_code,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'execute' and direction = 'inbound' and mov_date > '2020-07-01' THEN uwm.amount ELSE 0 END) as amountInbound
FROM user_wallet_movement uwm JOIN
     user_wallet uw
     ON uwm.wallet_id = uw.id JOIN
     app_user au
     ON uw.user_id = au.id
WHERE au.country IN ('AD', 'AC', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AI', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AW', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BM', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BV', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CC', 'CD', 'CF', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CR', 'CU', 'CV', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'EH', 'ER', 'ES', 'ET', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FK', 'FM', 'FO', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GF', 'GH', 'GI', 'GL', 'GM', 'GN', 'GP', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GT', 'GU', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HM', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IO', 'IQ', 'IR', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KP', 'KR', 'KW', 'KY', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MM', 'MN', 'MP', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MS', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NC', 'NE', 'NF', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NU', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PF', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PM', 'PN', 'PR', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RE', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SD', 'SE', 'SG', 'SH', 'SI', 'SJ', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SO', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SY', 'SZ', 'TC', 'TD', 'TF', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TK', 'TL', 'TM', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'UM', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VA', 'VC', 'VE', 'VG', 'VI', 'VN', 'VU', 'WF', 'WS', 'xA', 'xE', 'xF', 'XK', 'xN', 'xO', 'xS', 'YE', 'YT', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW')
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY country_code;
```

Otherwise, you will need to use a `LEFT JOIN`.  For that purpose, it is better to start with a countries table of some sort.  Do you have such a table?

Comment: No, sorry I should have probably mention this:
Not all countries are in table; so I would like the other countries which are not in table to be equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have all the countries from `table A` to show up even though `table b` has less number of countries then your `join` should be `LEFT` instead of `Inner`.

This way rows with no amount will be `null` in cases where the countries doesn't exist in `table B`. This null can be replaced using `COALESCE()`

`COALESCE` returns the first non-null value. if both are not null then it returns the first one.

```
SELECT
       au.country as country_code,
       COALESCE(SUM(uwm.amount), 0) as amountInbound
        FROM user_wallet_movement uwm
        LEFT JOIN user_wallet uw 
        ON uwm.wallet_id = uw.id
        LEFT JOIN app_user au
        ON uw.user_id = au.id
        WHERE
              status = 'execute'
              and direction = 'inbound'
              and mov_date > '2020-07-01'
              and au.country IN ('ALL THE COUNTRIES')
      GROUP BY 
            country_code
      ORDER BY 
            country_code
```